# Looking for parMetis visualizer?

Tags: finite-element, visualization, partitioning

Is there any visualizer for parMetis (mpmetis), which can visualize FEM mesh grids after partitioning?

Comment: Do you currently have a way of visualizing the unpartitioned grids?

Comment: Yes, I use gmsh [link](http://geuz.org/gmsh/)

Comment: Since v1.51, the changelog says it supports visualizing partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We used to use [GMV](http://www.generalmeshviewer.com/) back in the day. If you label each partition as though it was a constant material property, you can have GMV display and "explode" your mesh on that property. It works pretty well for modest partitions.

Comment: GMV is no longer available for free and is being commercialized. Is there any free alternative?

Comment: Ah, too bad! I only checked that it still existed, not what it took to get a copy. :) You have my apologies. I don't know of any  free tools for this off the top of my head. Some googling didn't turn up anything useful either.

Comment: Don't Visit or Paraview allow "exploding" views? We color plots based on partition all the time, I just never tried to explode a view.